# How to detect JavaScript postMessage source iframe's id?

Tags: javascript, iframe, event-handling

I have this code:

```html
<iframe src="..." id="iframe_01"></iframe>
<iframe src="..." id="iframe_02"></iframe>
```

```js
const eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? 'addEventListener' : 'attachEvent';
const eventer = window[eventMethod];
const messageEvent = eventMethod === 'attachEvent' ? 'onmessage' : 'message';

eventer(messageEvent, (e) => {
  console.log(e);
  // ...
});
```

What is the best way to detect the message sender iframe's `id`?

Comment: eventer(messageEvent, (e) => {
  console.log(e.target); // Can we know from `e.target`?
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas:

1. You might be able to get it by comparing the message `source` with the `contentWindow` property of the `iframe` elements (e.g., in a loop). You'd want to try this out on all of your target browsers to make sure that `event.source === iframe.contentWindow` works to identify the `iframe`.
2. You could have the `iframe` explicitly include it in the message. The `iframe`'s window should have access to the `iframe` element it's embedded in via the [`frameElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frameElement) property so in theory, at least for same-origin windows, `frameElement.id` would give the `iframe` that ID.

If neither of those works, you could use `postMessage` to tell the `iframe`s what ID to send back, or include the ID in the query string of the `iframe`'s URL so the `iframe` can get it from [`location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search).

Comment: Thank you! The `frameElement.id` was the simpliest solution for me.